# Difference on creating a CUDA context

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc, cuda-context

I've a program that uses three kernels. In order to get the speedups, I was doing a dummy memory copy to create a context as follows:

```
__global__ void warmStart(int* f)
{
    *f = 0;
}
```

which is launched before the kernels I want to time as follows:

```
int *dFlag = NULL;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dFlag, sizeof(int) );
warmStart<<<1, 1>>>(dFlag);
Check_CUDA_Error("warmStart kernel");
```

I also read about other simplest ways to create a context as `cudaFree(0)` or `cudaDevicesynchronize()`. But using these API calls gives worse times than using the dummy kernel.

The execution times of the program, after forcing the context, are `0.000031` seconds for the dummy kernel and `0.000064` seconds for both, the cudaDeviceSynchronize() and cudaFree(0). The times were get as a mean of 10 individual executions of the program.

Therefore, the conclusion I've reached is that launch a kernel initialize something that is not initialized when creating a context in the canonical way.

So, what's the difference of creating a context in these two ways, using a kernel and using an API call?

I run the test in a GTX480, using CUDA 4.0 under Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each CUDA context has memory allocations that are required to execute a kernel that are not required to be allocated to syncrhonize, allocate memory, or free memory. The initial allocation of the context memory and resizing of these allocations is deferred until a kernel requires these resources. Examples of these allocations include the local memory buffer, device heap, and printf heap.