# Performance drop in nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R

Tags: cuda, gpu, npp

I have a performance drop using the `nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R` function in two different architectures (GTX480 and GTX TITAN) involving also different CUDA version (v5.0 and v5.5 respectively).

In the first case (GTX480 and CUDA 5.0) the execution time of the function is

```
T = 0.00005 seconds
```

In the second case (GTX TITAN and CUDA 5.5) the execution time is

```
T = 0.969831 seconds
```

I have reproduced this behaviour with the following code:

```
// GTX480 nvcc -lnpp -m64 -O3 --ptxas-options=-v -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 --compiler-options -use_fast_math
// GTXTITAN nvcc -lnppi -m64 -O3 --ptxas-options=-v -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 --compiler-options -use_fast_math
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
// CUDA
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
// CUDA Nvidia Performance Primitives
#include <npp.h>

#include <assert.h>

#define w 256   // width
#define h 256   // height
#define b 16    // extra border

#define BORDER_TYPE 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // input data
    Npp8u* h_idata[w*h];
    // output data
    Npp8u* h_odata[(w+b)*(h+b)];

    /* MEMORY ALLOCTION AND INITIAL COPY OF DATA FROM CPU TO GPU */

    Npp8u *i_devPtr, *i_devPtr_Border;

    // size of input the data
    int d_Size = w * h * sizeof(Npp8u);
    // allocate input data
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMalloc( (void**) &i_devPtr, d_Size ) );
    // copy initial data to GPU
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMemcpy(i_devPtr, h_idata, d_Size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // size of output the data
    int d_Size_o = (w+b) * (h+b) * sizeof(Npp8u);    
    // allocation for input data with extended border
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMalloc( (void**) &i_devPtr_Border, d_Size_o ) );

    // create struct with ROI size given the current mask
    NppiSize SizeROI = {w, h};

    NppiSize SizeROI_Border = { SizeROI.width + b, SizeROI.height + b };

    // create events
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate( &start );
    cudaEventCreate( &stop );

    // NPP Library Copy Constant Border
    cudaEventRecord( start, 0 );
    NppStatus eStatusNPP = nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R(i_devPtr,SizeROI.width, SizeROI,
                    i_devPtr_Border, SizeROI_Border.width, SizeROI_Border,
                    b, b, BORDER_TYPE);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert( NPP_NO_ERROR == eStatusNPP );
    cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 );
    cudaEventSynchronize( stop );

    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    printf("T= %1.5f sg\n", milliseconds / 1000.0f);


    // copy output data from GPU
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMemcpy(h_odata, i_devPtr_Border, d_Size_o, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    /* free resources */
    cudaFree(i_devPtr);
    cudaFree(i_devPtr_Border);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

**Q:** Anyone is aware about this issue ?

This makes me ask the following question:

**Q:** How is `nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R` implemented? Does the function involve copy data from device to host, extend the border in the host and copy the result to the device?

**PS:** The machine with the TITAN has the GPU outside the box in a separated motherboard specially designed for multiple PCIe connections and it's connected via a PCIe wire. I have not seen any drawback in this configuration regarding other kernels I have tested.

Comment: Can you try running an API trace with nvprof? I would guess your timing is probably the victim of something that used to happen earlier in the process lifetime now happening lazily at kernel launch. The guve away would be that the kernel function still takes a few microseconds, but the cuLuanch that runs it takes hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: @talonmies I'll check the API trace in both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that the only difference is when/where API latencies are being accounted for during program execution, and the the underlying npp function itself doesn't have a vast different in performance between the two CUDA versions and GPU architectures.

My evidence for this hypothesis is this version of the code you posted:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <npp.h>

#include <assert.h>

#define w 256   // width
#define h 256   // height
#define b 16    // extra border

#define BORDER_TYPE 0

#define CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Npp8u* h_idata[w*h];
    Npp8u* h_odata[(w+b)*(h+b)];
    Npp8u *i_devPtr, *i_devPtr_Border;

    int d_Size = w * h * sizeof(Npp8u);
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMalloc( (void**) &i_devPtr, d_Size ) );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMemcpy(i_devPtr, h_idata, d_Size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    int d_Size_o = (w+b) * (h+b) * sizeof(Npp8u);    
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMalloc( (void**) &i_devPtr_Border, d_Size_o ) );

    NppiSize SizeROI = {w, h};
    NppiSize SizeROI_Border = { SizeROI.width + b, SizeROI.height + b };
    NppStatus eStatusNPP;  

#ifdef __WARMUP_CALL__
    // Warm up call to nppi function
    eStatusNPP = nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R(i_devPtr,SizeROI.width, SizeROI,
                    i_devPtr_Border, SizeROI_Border.width, SizeROI_Border,
                    b, b, BORDER_TYPE);

    assert( NPP_NO_ERROR == eStatusNPP );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
#endif

    // Call for timing
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaEventCreate( &start ) );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaEventCreate( &stop ) );

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaEventRecord( start, 0 ) );
    eStatusNPP = nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R(i_devPtr,SizeROI.width, SizeROI,
                    i_devPtr_Border, SizeROI_Border.width, SizeROI_Border,
                    b, b, BORDER_TYPE);

    assert( NPP_NO_ERROR == eStatusNPP );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaEventRecord( stop, 0 ) );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaEventSynchronize( stop ) );

    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
    printf("T= %1.5f sg\n", milliseconds / 1000.0f);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN( cudaMemcpy(h_odata, i_devPtr_Border, d_Size_o, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    cudaFree(i_devPtr);
    cudaFree(i_devPtr_Border);

    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaDeviceReset());

    return 0;
}
```

Note the warm up call to `nppiCopyConstBorder_8u_C1R` before the timed call. When I run it (CUDA 5.5 with linux on an sm_30 device), I see this:

```
~$ nvcc -lnppi -m64 -O3 --ptxas-options=-v -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 --compiler-options -use_fast_math pqb.cc 
~$ ./a.out 
T= 0.39670 sg

~$ nvcc -lnppi -m64 -O3 --ptxas-options=-v -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 --compiler-options -use_fast_math -D__WARMUP_CALL__ pqb.cc 
~$ ./a.out 
T= 0.00002 sg
```

ie. adding a warmup call totally changes the timed performance of the function. When I look at the API trace from `nvprof`, I see that both npp function calls take about 6 microseconds. However, the CUDA launch for the first call takes hundreds of millseconds when the second call takes about 12 microseconds.

So, as I mentioned in an earlier comment, there is some lazy process which is getting included in the timing of the CUDA 5.5 on Titan case that probably isn't on the CUDA 5.0 on Fermi case. That isn't a feature of npp though, as I guess that the performance of the actual function is as fast or faster on Titan than on the Fermi card.

Comment: You are totally right. However, I've tried the same but using the canonical way to create a CUDA context ()http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415204/how-to-create-a-cuda-context and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313930/difference-on-creating-a-cuda-context) and the behaviour is the same. Is possible that the first call to a function in the NPP library needs a different context initialization ?

Comment: I have updated the question with a `PS` regarding the configuration of the TITAN (although I have not seen any drawback with that).

Comment: In the first comment, I mean the behaviour is the same as in the question, not as in your answer :). Just in case.

Comment: @pQB: To be clear, this isn't context initialisation I am talking about. The context initialisation happens well before the function call (you have prior cudaMalloc calls for example). This is some sort of lazy setup for the kernel launch. In a (now deleted) comment Greg Smith from NVIDIA indicated that some things like local memory allocation and code loading actually happen lazily when cuLaunch is called. It the the cuLaunch itself which I see as consuming a lot of time on the first call.

Comment: Ok, got it. So,  It's implementation defined and happens behind the scenes, and therefore nothing to deal with?

Comment: @pQB: Quite probably. If this bothers you, you might want to complain to NVIDIA via a bug report. Personally I dislike the idea of lazy driver API behaviour. In my codes I want to have predictable, repeatable API latency and this sort of behaviour is the opposite of that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice (actually it bothers me but this is enough for now).

Comment: The standard practice is to call cudaFree(0) once at the top of your application - this forces all of the lazy initialization to occur, but is otherwise a no-op.

Comment: @JonathanCohen Using cudaFree(0) does not change the behaviour of the NPP example we are testing. The problem persists. It's definitely related with the first function call to the NPP library

Comment: @jonathancohen: the cudafree to trigger context initialization trick doesn't fix this anymore. there are lazy operations which occur at first kernel kernel call which are not performed during context establishment. Greg Smith suggested that things like local memory reservation happens at launch, not context establishment. that is different to what happened before cuda 5.5.